# Entity Framework crashed Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I just added EntityFramework to my MVC5 project. I`ve created classes and set up the connections string:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="UserDBContext" 
       connectionString="server=.; database = DDP; integrated security = true;"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

After debug Visual Studio is not responding and I have to remove it by Task Manager. I canot even debug to see what`s happen. What could do that ?

UPDATE

```
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"></defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="UserDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=.; Integrated Security=True; Initial Catalog = DDP;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: what database are you trying to connect to? this connection string doesn't really give away anything.

Comment: I want it to create database called "DDP' on my local machine server=.;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used wrong connection string in your `web.confing` in you case it looks like code for `SqlConnection.ConnectionString` when it is used from C# directly.

But in ASP.NET MVC with EF connection string in `web.confing` looks different, where you use `Data Source` instead of `server` and `Initial Catalog` instead of `database`, so in the end you connection string will look something like that:

```
<add name="UserDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DDP;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**Update**

Put your `<add ../>` on 1 line, move `Initial Catalog` before `Integrated Security` and then delete `;` after `Integrated Security=True` like below:

```
 <add name="UserDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DDP;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

If this code doesn't work, then if  you installed SQL Server Express with default settings use `.\SQLEXPRESS` instead of `.`:

```
<add name="UserDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DDP;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Still not responding I`ve edited my post. I copied there Web.config <entity framework> and <connectionsString>  Maybe there is smth wrong?

Comment: Hhaha thanks its working but after that I cannot login to SQL Management Studio i have some error trying to log in :(. Anyway thanks for help maybe this issuead I dont know :P